# Llamar a una función en una ruta dentro de un componente de NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Tengo formulada dos funciones en un componente de NodeJS con Express y MongoDB.

```
// Llamada al model de Company
const Company = require('../models/company');

// Encontrar y devolver el nombre de la compañía
const getCompanyName = (req, res) => {
    
    // Buscar desde parámetros en la url
    const byParams = (companyId) => {

        companyId = req.params.id;
            
        if(!companyId || companyId === null) return res.status(404).send({message: 'No such CompanyId or non-existent'});

        Company.findById(companyId, (err, company) => {
            
            if(err || !company ) return res.status(404).send({message: 'No such Company'});

            return res.status(200).send({company: company.name});
        });

    }
    
    // Buscar desde parámetros en el body
    const byBody = (params) => {

        params = req.body;

        let companyId = params.id;

        if(!companyId || companyId === null) return res.status(404).send({message: 'No such CompanyId or non-existent'});

        Company.findById(companyId, (err, company) => {
        
            if(err || !company ) return res.status(404).send({message: 'No such Company'});

            return res.status(200).send({company: company.name});
        });
    }

    byParams();
    byBody();

}
```

Cada función, estando por separadas en componentes, funciona bien, pero estoy repitiendo código una y otra vez para realizar las misma acciones.

La idea es tratar de simplificar el código lo más que se pueda.

Tenía la idea de incorporar un condicional para llamar una u otra función dependiendo de si los parámetros vienen por el body o por la url:

```
if(req.params) {
        byParams(req.params);
    } if(req.body) {
        byBody(req.body);
    } else {
        return res.status(200).send({message: 'No data was send'});
    }
```

Pero aquí nada funciona y devuelve como que nada existe.

Al final la idea es llamar a todo desde la siguiente ruta:

```
api.get('/getcompanyname/:id?', CompanyController.getCompanyName);
```

**Para cerrar la idea, quiero saber si se puede crear un componente como este, con dos funciones que realicen lo mismo pero que reciben datos de diferentes fuentes, y llamarlas por separado según sea el caso, pero con la misma ruta.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro que puedes, no necesitas declarar 2 funciones que realizan la misma tarea.

Si valoramos correctamente lo que haces en cada función, en esencia estás llamando al método [`findById()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) de un Modelo de [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com), por lo cual basta con escribir (o no, como veremos más adelante) una sola función que se encargue de esto, sin importar si la consulta fue realizada mediante una `query param` o mediante un valor en el cuerpo (`body`) de la solicitud.

***Una Función para gobernarlos a todos, una Función para encontrarlos, una Función para atraerlos a todos y ...***

La idea es escribir una función única que no tenga que lidiar con la forma en que se ha obtenido el dato (`id`), de esta forma la misma función recibe siempre un valor (sin importar su origen) y devuelve un resultado.

Una primera implementación sería la siguiente:

```js
const getCompany = id  => {
  if(!id) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: 'Falta valor de id'
    });
  }
  Company.findById(id, {_id: 0, name: 1}, (error, company) => {
    if(error) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        message: 'Ocurrió un error interno al procesar la solicitud, intente más tarde'
      });
    }
    if(!company) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: 'No se encontró ninguna compañía coincidente con la consulta'
      });
    }
    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'Ok',
      company: company.name
    });
  });
}
```

Y la podemos usar de la siguiente forma:

```js
const getCompanyName = (req, res) => {
  // declaramos la función
  const getCompany = id  => { ... } // resumimos para mostrar ejemplo
  
  let id = req.body.id ?? req.params.id;
  getCompany(id);
}
```

En el ejemplo anterior hemos usado el operador llamado [*Nullish coalescing operator (??)*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) para definir el valor de la variable `id`. Además hemos planteado 2 posibles escenarios usando la misma función.

Si el parámetro `id` viene dentro del cuerpo de la solicitud, entonces el mismo es asignado a nuestra variable, pero si el cuerpo de la solicitud no tiene un campo llamado `id`, el operador `??` devolverá el valor del lado derecho, en este caso el campo `id` que corresponde al objeto `params` de la solicitud. Si ambos valores son `undefined`, entonces la variable `id` contendrá `undefined`.

Luego, una vez obtenida la variable `id`, hacemos el llamado a la función que nos devuelve el nombre de la compañía. Esta función se encargará de manejar el caso cuando `id` sea `undefined`.

Visto lo anterior, resulta evidente que para obtener el valor buscado no hace falta una función específica declarada dentro del método `getCompanyName`, ya que podemos pasar directamente el valor `id` al método `findById` del Modelo.

¿Pero qué pasa si `id` es `undefined`?

Internamente, Mongoose traduce el llamado a `findById(undefined)` a `findOne({_id: null})` (recordemos que Mongoose usa el driver de NodeJS para MongoDB que sólo dispone de los métodos [`find()` y `findOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/retrieve/) para la obtención de datos).

Con esto, lo que quiero decir es que al final no hace falta declarar una función para la tarea a realizar, ya que podemos hacerlo de forma directa como muestro a continuación:

```js
const getCompanyName = (req, res) => {
  // obtenemos el valor del `id` 
  let id = req.body.id ?? req.params.id;
  // llamamos al método `findById` del modelo
  Company.findById(id, {_id: 0, name: 1}, (error, company) => {
    if(error) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        message: 'Ocurrió un error interno al procesar la solicitud, intente más tarde'
      });
    }
    if(!company) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: 'No se encontró ninguna compañía coincidente con la consulta'
      });
    }
    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'Ok',
      company: company.name
    });
  });
}
```

En el código anterior, me deshecho de la función `getCompany`, ya que en realidad no aporta nada y hace el código algo más complejo.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: funciona una maravilla